# The folder "/var/app/staging/storage/logs" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have laravel application deployed on aws elastic beanstalk using amazon bucket auto deployments, but whenever new changes has been pushed laravel application gives storage/logs directory error due to permissions. Already tried using .platform postdeployed hooks but its still giving error.

Here is the solution In tried but did not work.
Here is the `.platform/hooks/postdeploy/50_run_something_after_app_deployment.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod -R 777 storage
mkdir -p /storage/logs
chmod -R 777 /storage/logs
```

I also create .config file under .ebextension folder to make the .platform hook executeable.

```
container_commands:
  40_post_deploy:
    command: chmod -R 777 .platform/hooks/postdeploy/50_run_something_after_app_deployment.sh
```

I want to fix the logs error using `.platform hooks`.